# IPython Language Kernel Implementation in Erlang

Tags: python, erlang, ipython, zeromq

I'm currently building an Erlang language kernel backend for IPython, and I'm testing it out in the console.

**What I have working:**

- Start ipython console and the erlang kernel
- Erlang kernel reads contents of kernel.json file which contains all the port numbers for zmq
- Create zmq bindings for the `shell`, `heartbeat`, `control`, `iopub` sockets using the erlzmq2 library.
- Created functions to parse messages from IPython
- Create a process for the heartbeat server to run on and return messages to IPython
- Created a process for the Shell Socket to receive and respond to the following messages

  - kernel_info_request -> kernel_info_reply
  - execute_request -> execute_reply
- Also, the iopub socket sends these messages

  - status
  - pyout

If you're still with me, all of this works.
The first IPython `In[1]:` prompt appears and I can type code, send it to the backend and receive the execute_request message from ipython.

However, my problem is after this sequence of events where I receive an execute_request:

- sent a busy status to IPython
- executed the code and captured the output string
- sent pyout message to IPython
- sent execute_reply to IPython
- sent idle status to IPython

After these messages are sent, nothing happens. I receive no more messages from IPython and the code execution is not output to the console, nor does a new prompt appear requesting more input from the user.

I'm just wondering if I'm sending the messages in the correct order, or am I sending the correct messages?

Comment: First of all: This is awesome! Is the code already available somewhere? Second: Which version of IPython are you using?

Comment: Hi, The code is not available yet :( . It will be available soon (once I clean it up an refactor some code)... maybe next week :) . I'm using IPython 2.0.0-dev with the messaging protocol version 4.1

Comment: In case you're wondering, IErlang is now available at http://github.com/robbielynch/ierlang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on this for a couple of weeks now, and I've found no solution to the console problem.

However, I've found a work-around that allows more than one input.

**Firstly** I did not use the language profile I had previously used. This language profile simply tells IPython what kernel to use and what encryption string to use.

**Next**, I started to use the notebook instead of the console. In the hope it would offer more inputs. And, it did. :)

To start ipython with a specified kernel, I used the following command:

```
ipython2 notebook --KernelManager.kernel_cmd='["/usr/lib/erlang/bin/escript", "ipython_kernel.erl", "{connection_file}"]' --Session.key="" --Session.keyfile=""
```

**In the above command**, I specify the kernel command, and provide the following:

- the location of the executable to run my erlang kernel
- the name of my kernel
- and connection file

**Next**, I specify the session key and the session keyfile as empty strings.

Providing the kernel is correctly written, it allows multiple entries of code and markdown into ipyton/ierlang.

Here is a sample of ierlang at it's early stages:

[image: The first IErlang Notebook]

I hope this post helps out anyone else that's struggling to develop kernels for ipython. :)

---

## **[Update- April 12, 2014]**

I finally figured out the problem. It turns out, when sending erlang strings(list of ints) over zmq, they arrive at IPython's message parser as a list of ints.

I presumed, they'd automatically convert to strings, but they don't.

### **Solution**

The solution was to edit the `IPython/kernel/zmq/session.py` file to allow it to parse erlang strings.

This has allowed for the output prompt to appear in the console and in the notebook versions of IErlang.